# stft function on Matlab 'FrequencyRange' is not a recognized parameter

Tags: matlab

I'm following a demo code on mathworks website:

```
        [S,f] = stft(audioBuffered,Fs, "Window", win, "OverlapLength", samplesOverlap, 'FrequencyRange', 'onesided');
```

trying to execute it Matlab returns an error:

```
Error using stft 'FrequencyRange' is not a recognized parameter
```

The problem is that i need a onesided stft and on Matlab's documentation it's clear that 'FrequencyRange' is a parameter of the function stft.

Anyone this problem? How can i solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `'FrequencyRange'` parameter to `stft` is new in MATLAB R2020b. (You can see this by checking the reference page from R2020a https://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2020a/signal/ref/stft.html ). So, you need to update to R2020b, or not use the `'FrequencyRange'` parameter.

In general, I'd recommend trying to use the documentation pages corresponding to the version of MATLAB you're using.

Comment: oh my bad! Because of i try to have Matlab always up to date i wasn't thinking about it but I missed the last version on semptember (still at 2020a). Thanks!